# Laptop screen only works if HDMI is connected

Tags: laptop, display, hdmi

I have a strange error. My laptop only works if the HDMI is connected to a television (didn't try VGA/monitor but I guess is the same).

If I start the laptop disconnected the screen is black, but works if I plug the cable. I tried with the fn key, but doesn't work either.

The laptop is an Acer Aspire 5552 Series with Windows 10. Tried to upgrade to Anniversary Edition to see if was a W10 issue, but the problem persist.

Thanks.

Comment: Is there any situation where the internal monitor is working? Can you start with the HDMI cable connected and change the Windows settings so that windows uses the internal monitor? Have you tried a Live-Linux USB stick? ... Does the internal monitor ever show something at all?

Answer (score 1):

The Win + P hotkey is the display switcher so you could try pressing that a few times to see if it switches to your laptop display.